# How download instagram images in web browser in pc?

Tags: instagram

I am trying to download instagram images from my google chrome web browser from pc, but there is now download option and can't see 'save image as' option on right click also. So i found one solution and i put it on answer section.

Comment: go to http://gramfeed.com and look for the same picture, it will allow u to download the pictures

Comment: yes we can use inspect element from browser or using browser extentions like dinstagram, check this out http://oopsreview.com/many-ways-to-download-photo-or-video-on-instagram/

Comment: Use https://saveaxe.now.sh/  no ads, download all images, videos etc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right Click --> Select 'View Page Source' after navigating to the new tab Press Ctrl + F and type '.jpg'. You will find a link. Copy the link and open it in new tab. You will get image and you can download that image.

Comment: Currently, If you try that you will get an "URL signature mismatch" error accessing the image.

Comment: I would suggest using the browser developer tool (CTRL+SHIFT+i in Firefox or Chrome), go to "network" tab and filter images elements to find the one you are looking for. Add `?size=l` to the URL of the page, and repeat the steps, if you need the image in HD.

Comment: On instagram web site invoke developers console and paste the code.
```javascript
function getUrls() {
 const urls = []
    // ._aang or whatever the class's name of the div element
 const rows = document.querySelectorAll('._aang')
 rows.forEach(row => {
  const images = row.querySelectorAll('img')
  images.forEach(image => {
   urls.push(image.src)
  })
 })
 return urls
}

getUrls().join('\n')
```